# Use Apache to redirect any requests to node app and redirect http to https

Tags: node.js, apache, express, https

I have a express app running together with a apache2 server. I am trying to setup a VirtualHost that proxys to my express app (Which only serves HTTPS)

So I want to rewrite the http request to my https virtual host that then proxys to my node.js express app.

The express app runs on port 3500

But when I try to reach test.nw-system.de/api-docs I get a 404 Error.

I am running a Linux Ubuntu 18.04 Server, that is running as a VM under ESXi.
I have a Apache2 Server running together with my Node.js App.
I used to connect to it via: https://nw-system.de:3500, which works without an issue. But now I wanted to get rid of the port in the URL and use a subdomain instead. The express app only uses https (For encryption of username/password).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.nw-system.de
        ServerAdmin administrator@n-network.de
       RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
 
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName test.nw-system.de
        ProxyPass /* http://localhost:3500/
        ProxyPassReverse /* http://localhost:3500/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to reach http://test.nw-system.de/api-docs I expect to get redirected to https://test.nw-system.de/api-docs and then see the swagger API documentation which is hosted by the express app.
Also I expect my api to be reachable under: https://test.nw-system.de/api/v1

Eg:
https://test.nw-system.de/api/v1/items
which returns a JSON response

Comment: You don't need `*` in `/*`

Comment: Also, you should probably change `http://localhost:3500/` to `https://localhost:3500/`

Comment: ty for you help. Now I just have issues with ESXi.